# Quoting some one is bad?

Tags: discussion

I am pretty new on Stack Overflow. Normally when I do articles, I do quote people and put in the references. But, not very long time go I put a quote from Wikipedia in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544342/why-does-double-have-signed-zero), and at the end of it I put (source). I don't know why, but it looks like people just get "mad" because of it.

On Stack Overflow should we not quote others' work?

Any constructive advice on how to give an answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you feel like you are answering the question using your own expertise, or merely stringing together quotes from other primary sources?  Are your quotes the vast majority of the content of your answer, or do the quotes merely support your own words?  Anyone can go to Wikipedia and read an article; people come to Stack Overflow to ask experts their questions and benefit from that expertise.

Comment: Quoting is good. Copy & pasting without attribution is bad. You fixed the missing attribution, I don't think there's a problem now

Comment: Note the double quote button at the top of the answer box- you can select text and hit that button, and it will highlight that section of the text as a quote. That will make it clearer what is a quote and what is not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know the concept because I work with numerical algorithm, I just don't know how to put in a good english like the one was there.

Comment: And I did put the source, I always do.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I comment like that is easy to understand, and more than welcome, in contrast of using sarcasm to say the same thing.

Comment: Well, I read your answer, and I don't think you're actually answering the question that was asked (upvotes notwithstanding).  Your answer describes what +0 and -0 are, but you don't explain why they exist.  In the absence of the quoted text, your answer seems [link-only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I as planning to do it so, but I waste the time responding to the comments. Nevertheless, the issue that people raise was about the copy past. But, as soon I got from work, I will edit the question and improved.

Comment: Oh, you gave the source from the beginning (albeit a bit obscured). I apologize. In that case, I guess the only thing left to do in the future is to make super sure that it's crystal clear you're quoting. Quoting from Wikipedia is not a problem in itself

Comment: @Pekka Np, the main reason that I brought this question here. It so, I can full understand in how should or nor give question. Until know I did not know it was a problem copy past something.

Comment: Yeah. In that case, I guess the only thing left for you to do in the future is to make super sure that it's always crystal clear you're quoting someone (by using the "quote" formatting). Sometimes it may not answer the question, but quoting from Wikipedia is not a problem in itself, and not forbidden.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure all the answers here actually address the issue. The user put the material in a quote block. The user also included the "source" link to Wikipedia. I [recently had an edit rejected for a similar reason](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/463), and I'm just as confused and baffled as dreamcrash.... well, not *that* baffled and confused... ;)  I think I know why my edit was rejected... but it would be cool to get an official Stack Exchange response as to what is and isn't good attribution.

Comment: @jmort253: If you write an essay for university, the teacher expects it to be your own work, not the work of others.  It doesn't really matter if you attribute properly; the work should be your own work supported by quotes, not primarily quotes from other sources.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Yeh, I was thinking that was why. However, it makes it harder to improve link-only answers when you're not the original poster. I'd rather just flag it as not an answer and have the damn thing deleted than try to improve the post and get shut down. ;)

Comment: @jmort253: That is the usual end game, yes.  Posting links is lazy; enabling that laziness by fixing people's link-only answers with quotations (also lazy) kinda disrespects those folks who are trying to post real answers.

Comment: Funnily enough, one of the people complaining about quoting wikipedia has quoted wikipedia.

Comment: @Asas A person you read a answer that have (source) on it know that the answer was from that source. Is cleaner that putting the name, imagining if it was someone blog? Should I put "From blog blabla" and promote the blog in SO?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - When I post answers of my own, I go into great detail, one only need to check my activity to see that I am very thorough. However, something just really bugs me about answers that contain just a link and nothing else. My approach may not have been the best way to fix that problem, but I thought it was "less lazy" than merely flagging it as not an answer and moving on. This whole experience has sort of turned me off to trying to help people improve their link-only answers. There were times when I provided valid edits, and had stubborn people roll them back.

Comment: @dreamcrash If you are quoting the content of blog blabla then yes, they deserve explicit attribution and any attention that your post generates.

Comment: @jmort253: I too have tried adding quoted material to link-only answers to fix them up, but I've never been wholly satisfied with the result; this post clearly illustrates that the practice is problematic.  Users whose link-only answers are deleted can always post a new one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Agreeed. They always look better when the original poster fixes the post.

Comment: @Asad Fair enough, I did not that, I will put the name of the source as a title. However, I had seen before quotes like in SO similar to the one I did, from high reputation users, so I assume that I was normally to quote like that.

Comment: Hi dreamcrash, follow [Asad's template](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156651/155826), as this format seems to have the best results. 1) Put formatted link at the top that describes the source of the material, 2) put quoted material in quote block. 3) provide your own unique summary.

Comment: @dreamcrash Your answer in its current state is perfect. It is accurate, quotes a source properly, and proceeds to elaborate the material quoted. Nice one.

Comment: Thanks to all to clarifying. All could be solve by me not rush to answering, or if some had just said. "Put block quotes".

Comment: @RobertHarvey sr, do you mind taking out the -1, since I already edit the question, and I believe it answer the question also.

Comment: I didn't downvote, and I don't have the ability to change anyone else's vote

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Sorry I got the wrong impression that you did. Sure, didn't pass my mind to take others downvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you quote a source, format it as a quote, so it is easily distinguishable from your own content. Like this:

[Quoting dreamcrash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156648/155826):

> I am pretty new on SO, normally when I do articles I do quote people
>   and put the references. But, not very long I put in a answer to this
>   question a quote from wikipedia, and at the end of it I put (source).
>
> I don't know why but looks like people just get "mad" because of it.
>
> My question is, on SO we should not quote others work? Any
>   constructive advice on how to give an answer will be appreciated.

That said, it is generally a good idea to have original content that introduces or elaborates on the material you have quoted, no matter how self explanatory the quote.

Comment: "That said, it is generally a good idea to have original content that introduces or elaborates on the material you have quoted, no matter how self explanatory the quote.".  I've never been accused of being a plagiarizer when quoting material *and* providing explanation. This is the key piece that dreamcrash is missing.

Comment: @Asad Thanks for the inside.

Answer (score 3):

You should quote if you just copy other peoples content.

But it would be best to put it in your own words and give an answer that fits the question best. And personally I don't like that wikipedia content because it's hard to get. It tends to be spelled very formal.

Answer (score 3):

Note the double quote button at the top of the answer box- you can select text and hit that button, and it will format that section of the text as a quote. That will make it clearer what is a quote and what is not.

In most cases, an answer should be more than just a quote and a link. (One exception might be a very specific question about a language feature, and a quote from the documentation that precisely answers it- though even in those cases I would usually put a sentence afterwards summarizing it).

Comment: If you look at his answer, that's what he did. However, people are still asserting that it's plagiarism, even though he put the text in a quote block and also included a link to the source.

Comment: @jmort253 It wasn't actually originally formatted as a quote, and didn't even explicitly mention Wikipedia (just had a hyperlink entitled `source`). The accusations weren't so much ones of plagiarism as of unoriginality, since there wasn't much to go with the quotes. Additionally, I think people tend to frown on Wikipedia as a source here.

Comment: @jmort253: no, he hadn't put it in a quote block, he has edited it as such since my answer. See the edit history.

Comment: @Asad and David, I see that now. Thanks for pointing this out. It does sound like dreamcrash could have done a better job of making it clear where the material came from. Additionally, I think Robert Harvey is right. dreamcrash should also have elaborated on the content and provided his/her own explanation as well.

Comment: @jmort253 Actually, checking now Robert Harvey was actually the one who edited the question to include a quote block, not dreamcrash.

Comment: Ah, you're right. This was the edit right before RH's: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13544352/3

Comment: @DavidRobinson I put block quote, as soon I read the answer of Asad here.

Comment: Before that I was assuming (wrongly) that just putting (source) was enough. I had read Faq, I and did not remember reading about it, maybe it was nice to have a subsection for this, i don't know.